# bash read command. read line to symbol ^@ (as can i see in vim) and other part of line is ignored

Tags: image, file, bash

I try to read /dev/stdin using command read. But part of lines are not reads
What I do wrong?
Lines are reads to symbol ^@

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-Type: text/plain"
echo
IFS=$'\n'
while read -d $'\n'
do
echo $REPLY
done
```

POST http://79.135.220.173/post.png
RESPONSE http://79.135.220.173/response.png

Comment: I'm confused. Are you doing an HTTP POST of an image file to a shell script? what are you doing?

Comment: Input is image. Yes it worked when I read from POST_DATA=$(</dev/stdin); echo "$POST_DATA" But when I migrate site to server. At server echo return NULL

Comment: If you're reading an image and echoing it back the content type is certainly wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^@` is a legible representation of the ASCII null character.

C uses the null character as a string terminator, and bash is implemented in C.

Most likely bash's `read` function reads the entire line into a buffer which is assigned to `$REPLY`.  When that buffer is passed to the built-in `echo` command, it treats the null character as a line terminator.

For the code in your question, you could use the `cat` command rather than using bash's `read` to read a line at a time.  (`cat`, at least the GNU coreutils version, doesn't have a problem with null characters):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-Type: text/plain"
echo
cat
```

The final `cat` command simply copies stdin to stdout.

If you need to do some processing on the input before printing it, you might consider using Perl rather than bash for this script; Perl strings, unlike C strings, can contain embedded null characters.

Or can you arrange for the input not to contain any null characters?

Answer (score 0):

`read` will read from stdin (or whatever descriptor you specify with `-u`) until it encounters a newline character (or whatever you specified with `-d`), splitting what is read on the characters in `IFS` and assigning each token to the variables you specify, or to `REPLY` if none were specified. The final variable always gets all remaining input that was read.

So, since you did not specify `-d` then REPLY should contain, for you, all input up to the first newline character. This will happen once per loop, so your script should read and echo every line that is sent to it and never terminate.